# How do I export a Jooq query into a CSV file?

Tags: spring-boot, csv, pdf, jooq

I'm using `jooq` to write my `SQL` queries. I've written a query that joins three tables and now I want to export the result as a `CSV` file.

I tried using the `formatCSV()` method specified in the `JOOQ` docs. I'm storing the Context in a List. I'm using `spring-boot` as the backend.

The query works fine and I'm getting the expected result. Now I want to export it as a `CSV` file. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with your `formatCSV()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Use `query.fetch().formatCSV(new FileWriter("filename.csv"))`